# fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/vast-basin-36215.git/' not found

Tags: heroku

I actually deleted the app named vast-basin-36215 on the Heroku dashboard, I'm trying to deploy my project on another app I just made, which has a different name. I did that command by replacing the name of the old app with the new one but I got the following:

**remote:! No such app as vast-basin-36215.**

**fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/vast-basin-36215.git/' not found**

[vew error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDVRf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the error image log you provided, you missed some important messages. when you did:

> `git add .`

you got response

> ....
> "nothing to commit."

that means that after the first command heroku create you should have `CD` to the new repository folder and only then continue with the flow

```
heroku create barishal-gadget-store
CD barishal-gadget-store
git add .
...    
...
```